# Save image in C# Windows Store apps

Tags: c#, image, windows-8

```
      EDITED
```

Here is a detailed descrption...

I have four buttons, first button uses fileOpenPicker and selects an image and displays on a image control

second button, will capture the image using CamerCaptureUi .. and displays the photo on the same image control...

Third button is to edit the image.. When I click on this button Aviary SDK will be initialized, I will edit my image.

The edited image will be displayed on a new image control (say Img2).

using the fourth button, I have to save this edited image[img2]. I used filesavepicker, but no where I'm passing the control name img2 or its source.

Please help !!

Comment: How are you displaying image ? After editing the image, where will the image gets stored ?

Comment: Save the image where? To a file (roaming or local), to SkyDrive, to memory?

Comment: this is pretty close to a dupe of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16858376/download-and-save-image-in-pictures-library-through-windows-8-metro-xaml-app/16868277#16868277 from which you can pull some working code

Comment: Xyroid: The image will be displayed on a different image control

Comment: Patrick: Save the image to picture library...

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [FileSavePicker](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/br207871.aspx) class to choose a destination for your file. When you have the destination, use the methods of [FileIO](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/Hh701440) ([WriteBytesAsync](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/windows/apps/windows.storage.fileio.writebytesasync) for instance) to write the contents of the file.

Comment: Patrick: I Used FileSavePicker, I gave my destination folder, i defined the formats did everything... but all i'm saving is a blank image..

I'm no where passing the image control name<image2> in the filesave picker code...

could you please post a sample code, on how to save a static image which is already displayed on a image control !!! 

Would be helpful

Comment: Did you use a memorystream when saving? What size is the blank image? Is it saved with zero bytes?

Comment: No.. I haven't used any memorystream... the size is 0 bytes

Comment: What are you doing then? How do you get the image and saving it?

Comment: I used fileSavePicker without memoryStream. I'm getting a blank image.
I don't know where to pass the image control [img2]

Need help !!

Comment: The image that i'm getting after the editing is a writableBitMap ... How do i save this image...

Comment: Does this help? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7378946/saving-bitmap-as-png-on-wp7